# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: linking mistake?

Tags: c++, opencv, linker, clang

I am new to cpp, want to have a implementation of particle filter, I try to run the code here https://github.com/NewProggie/Particle-Filter, which is a structured and easy understanding project. But when I try to compile and link:

```
g++ $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv)  -I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_1/include -I /usr/local/Cellar/gsl/1.16/include  -stdlib=libc++   main.cpp -o main
```

I have following linking problem:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"colorFeatures::colorFeatures()", referenced from:
  _main in main-2b4c23.o
"colorFeatures::~colorFeatures()", referenced from:
  _main in main-2b4c23.o
"adaboostDetect::detectObject(_IplImage*, CvRect**)", referenced from:
  _main in main-2b4c23.o
"adaboostDetect::adaboostDetect()", referenced from:
  _main in main-2b4c23.o
"tracker::addObjects(_IplImage*, CvRect*, int)", referenced from:
  _main in main-2b4c23.o
"tracker::initTracker(_IplImage*, CvRect*, int, int)", referenced from:
  _main in main-2b4c23.o
"tracker::showResults(_IplImage*)", referenced from:
  _main in main-2b4c23.o
"tracker::next(_IplImage*)", referenced from:
  _main in main-2b4c23.o
"tracker::tracker()", referenced from:
  _main in main-2b4c23.o
"tracker::~tracker()", referenced from:
  _main in main-2b4c23.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any kind person has ideas about this problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: It would be simpler to use `CMake` to generate a makefile since the project provides a `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: Try to add library search path to opencv library

g++ $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv)  -I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_1/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/1.16/include -L/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_1/lib  -stdlib=libc++   main.cpp -o main

Comment: @drescherjm:  thanks, but could you in detail tell me how to do next? I could use cmake to generate CMakeFiles folder, main.app, cmake_install.cmake, but what to do with these stuff? thanks

Comment: After you generate the makefile. you execute `make` or `cmake --build .` in the build folder

Comment: @drescherjm, ok, thanks a lot and then use make to work. But could you kindly tell me how to solve the problem listed directly(not an alternative way), any link or clue will be welcomed, thanks for your help and patience

Comment: I believe you are missing commands to link. I can't help with the exact settings because I build / develop mostly with Visual Studio using CMake to generate my project files.  In your case the generated makefile may help if you want to understand. I say may because I suspect it is more complicated than you need..

Comment: @drescherjm, ok, i see the situation, thanks a lot, you saved me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have gsl installed properly
B) pass to g++ a reference to the lib directory where the gsl libraries are located (probably something like /usr/lib or /usr/local/lib, these should both be default locations for the linker to search), and also to where the header files are, and also tell the linker to do the linking.

```
g++ -o <name of executable> -L/path/to/gsl/libs -I/path/to/headers -lgsl <name of source file>
```

the -L tells it where to find the libraries (.so files on linux, .dylib on OS X), -I tells it where to find the headers, -l (that's a lower case L) tells it to link to the library, which would be named libgsl.so or libgsl.dylib.

First just try adding the -lgsl flag, then if it can't find libgsl.so (or .dylib), add the -L flag. NOTE: /path/to/gsl/libs and /path/to/headers are not what you should literally put in there, but replace them with the actual paths on your system.